# Audio Stream prevents sleep

Tags: windows-10, audio, sleep

I installed windows 10 recently after a factory reset of my Dell inspiron 3542, but I'm having issues with the sleeping process.

I put the computer to sleep, it doesn't.. and looses battery.

I ran `powercfg -requests` and I found under system an audio stream is being used.

So I did a `powercfg -requestsoverride` of my driver, but it didn't work. I uninstalled the driver completely still no chance.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth trying:

Go to Control Panel -> Sound -> Speakers -> Advanced and untick "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device".

Comment: Thanks but I actually fixed it :D.. I downloaded process explorer and found out that Cortana was using audioses.dll so I disabled it...Now it's all good..

Comment: Did not work for me.